# Has Anyone Used Chronic or ChronicDuration in VoltRB?

Tags: client, duration, voltrb, opalrb, chronic

I've put the `chronic` and `chronic_duration` gems in my `Gemfile`, and everything works fine in `volt console`. However, if I try anything on the client side, I get a name error. I tried requiring them in a client-side initializer, but that didn't help.

Any tips?

Comment: Yes. In my app/config/clients_configuration.rb file.

Comment: I would try to require it in the controller and use it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add to Elia's answer, in Volt you can put `use_gem` in `config/dependencies.rb` (in the docs [here](http://docs.voltframework.com/en/docs/lib.html))

This does work to load Chronic but it looks like Chronic won't run in Opal because it uses mutable strings - I get the following error:

`Uncaught NotImplementedError: #<< not supported. Mutable String methods are not supported in Opal.`

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the correct answer. I tried to port Chronic to RubyMotion and could not because it uses `require` and that's not supported. These are hands-down the best time libraries, but they rely on features defined in the core Ruby spec but omitted in some implementations. Sigh. Obviously, @elia's answer was also correct, but SO makes me choose one or the other.

Comment: no problem, keep this as the right answer :) – Anyway I found that most gems will accept PRs for avoiding the use of mutable strings as they're seldom a perf bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the gem's paths to the paths Opal/sprockets searches looking for files.

For gems there's a nice helper:

```
 Opal.use_gem "chronic"
```

That should go in CRuby code (MRI) as early as possible during the initialization process.